# UML class diagram association implemented in Java classes

Tags: java, associations, uml, diagram, class-diagram

I have following UML class associations wanna control if im right or wrong(Methods are not needed here):

[image]

Nr 1:

```
import java.util.*;


public  class Dictionary {

    private DictEntry[] entry;

   ArrayList<DictEntry> book = new ArrayList<DictEntry>();

   public Dictionary(){
       entry = new DictEntry[3];
       entry[0] = new DictEntry("Abc");
       entry[1] = new DictEntry("Def");
       entry[2] = new DictEntry("Ghi");

       book.add(new DictEntry("Bla"));
       book.add(new DictEntry("Blub"));
       book.add(new DictEntry("Bli"));
   }

}

public class DictEntry{

    private String entry;

    public DictEntry(String entry) {
        this.entry = entry;

    }

}
```

The first and the third diagram are the same!

My Question are for Aggregation and composition if im right here and if im not,what can i add?

Aggregation:

```
public  class Dictionary {

    private DictEntry entry;


}


public class DictEntry{



}
```

Composition:

```
import java.util.*;


public  class Dictionary {

    private DictEntry[] entry;


}

DictEntry:

public class DictEntry{
}
```

The only question i have is how does the second diagram if i have the first one,the direction to Dictionary is not clear in my implementations.

Answer (score 2):

You have got it wrong dude, No1. the first association is like this

```
public  class Dictionary {
private DictEntry d0,d1,d2;
}
public class DictEntry{}
```

the second one would be like this

```
private DictEntry d0,d1,d2;
}
public class DictEntry{
private Dictionary owner;
}
```

The 3rd. one is used when the `Dictionary` would have (n)references from `DicEntry` classes, but the size is unknown, it's useful when `Dictionary` is kinda abstract definition.

the 4th. one(Aggregation) is used when `Dictionary` is kinda container for `DicEntry` but with `Dictionary` object finalization(kill), the hosted `DicEntry` objects would continue their lives(keep persistent)

```
public  class Dictionary {
private List<DicEntry> dics;//with Dictionary termination, dics instance would be kept alive
}
public class DictEntry{}
```

and teh last one is like the 4th. one with a difference, and this is when the `Dictionary` get finalized, this will caused the finalizing the hosted objects `DicEntry`

I really cannot show the aggregation/composition with code, but the diagram tells the developer that the hosted object will be available after host class termination or not.

Comment: Ok. So i can implement the third if i set the Dictionary class Abstract with the same attributes as the first one, right? I have an reflexive class diagram in an another question,would be nice if you can look where the mistakes are. Big thanks for everything u did now and before :)

Comment: your definition for aggregation is wrong. aout the 3rd. one, as I said, the diagram tells the developer that the `Dictionary` would have 0->n-number of `DicEntry` classes, but the actual(exact) definition would be defined by a 2nd. inherited class, there is no need to make the `Dictionary` abstract.